# Checkstyle does not detect empty javadoc comment

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, checkstyle

Could you please help me to configure Checkstyle to warn me if the javadoc comment is empty?

Checkstyle dest not warn me in the following case (javadoc comment is totally missing):

```
/**
 *
 */
public enum MyType{ EQUALS }
```

I have checked the documentation [here](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html), but I could not see anything related this issue.

Comment: Well, have you configured Checkstyle to check for this? Which check are you expecting to trigger?

Comment: I have checked the documentation but I could not see anything related to this issue. I have no idea which property I need to set in the config file.

Comment: It is not missing, it is empty.

Comment: You are right, I have updated my question. Any idea how to check empty javadoc comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you can use the `Style Javadoc` Checkstyle module in the `Javadoc Comments` section. From the Checkstyle [documentation on Style Javadoc](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocStyle):

> Validates Javadoc comments to help ensure they are well formed. The
>   following checks are performed:
>
> - Ensures the first sentence ends with proper punctuation (That is a period, question mark, or exclamation mark, by default). Javadoc
>     automatically places the first sentence in the method summary table
>     and index. Without proper punctuation the Javadoc may be malformed.
>     All items eligible for the {@inheritDoc} tag are exempt from this
>     requirement.
> - Check text for Javadoc statements that do not have any description. This includes both completely empty Javadoc, and Javadoc with only
>     tags such as @param and @return.

Make sure to check the `checkEmptyJavadoc` checkbox:

[image: Style Javadoc]